# Question about how magnets work

Tags: magnetic-fields

So I was watching this vid- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nhmJPMi4FU&t=1m0s

Please watch from 1:00 to 2:00

Now I have some questions-

1) He says that *the north pole of the magnetic field will be on the top of the electron if the electron spins in the clockwise direction*. But how can we know what the top of the electron is? I mean, how do we figure out its top if its a ball shaped particle?(actually I know that its a wave function and yada yada ya)

2) Can anyone please explain the **paired electrons** thing? I don't really get it. Also, can an atom have more than 1 paired electrons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first question: Its basically the right hand thumb rule. Consider any spinning ball with one point marked as 'top of the ball', suppose you are looking at it from the top and it is spinning anticlockwise. Then the magnetic field will be towards the top. What if you chose the other point as 'top'? Then when you look at it, it will spin clockwise and the magnetic moment will be towards the bottom (which was earlier the top). So no matter which way you look at it, the magnetic field is in the same direction. Another way to state it is that curl the fingers of your right hand in the direction of rotation and the thumb will point in the direction of the magnetic field.

Note: we can apply the same classical theory to an electron and say its spinning. But according to quantum mechanics, it has 'spin angular momentum' But it isnt actually spinning.

About your second question, You will need to study basic concepts of chemistry to understand what are orbitals and how electrons are paired. Look up "Hund's Rule" on the internet.

edit: while writing the answer, i forgot that an elecron is negative in charge and so the field will actually be in the opposite direction which the right hand rule gives.

---

**Further explanation**:
It has been experimentally observed that all magnetic fields are produced by currents*. Straight currents produce circular magnetic fields (see diagram below) and circular currents produce straight magnetic fields (see diagram below). The direction of magnetic field around a straight current is given by one of the right hand thumb rules "Point thumb towards current; curl your fingers. The fingers now give the direction of curling om magnetic field." A current loop produces a magnetic field similar to a hypothetical "short magnetic dipole" with "north and south poles". (Please remember that all magnetic field are produced by currents and thus the poles are imaginary. No magnetic [mono]pole has been found. (at least till now)). The direction of poles of a current loop is given by the right hand thumb rule "curl fingers towards current; thumb points north". So since a single current loop produces a field like a short magnetic dipole, we might expect a solenoid with lots of current loops to produce a field like a bar magnet, and this expectation is correct. But since I said that all magnetic fields are due to current, you might wonder why a magnet produces a magnetic field. Does the magnet have currents flowing in it? The answer is yes, all atoms in a magnet have unpaired electrons spinning** and thus they all behave like *permanent current loops*.
Now the thing is that we define direction of current to be "direction of motion of positive charges". So if the electron rotates** anticlockwise, the current is clockwise (opposite to direction of motion of electron). So the right hand thumb rule now says "curl fingers *opposite* to direction of motion of electron; thumb points north." So I hope you have now understood both the mechanism by which magnetic fields are created by a magnet, and the right hand thumb rule(s).

Diagrams to help understanding:
[image: Magnetic field of a long wire]

[image: Magnetic field of a current loop]
Magnetic field of a current loop

*Actually changing electric field can also produce a magnetic field but right now I'm talking about magnetostatics only.

**An electron does not actually rotate or spin according to Quantum Mechanics, but you can think that it is rotating both about its axis and in its "orbit".

Comment: oh, ok thanks!! But one question, doesnt the direction of the thumb in the right hand rule point towards the direction of the current and not towards the magnetic field.

Comment: There are many ways to use the right hand thumb rule. In one version, we curl our fingers towards magnetic field to get the current and in other we  curl our fingers towards the current to get the magnetic field, and in still another, we curl fingers from the current to the field to get the force etc. Basically all these arise from the definition of the vector cross product. If you look at the Maxwell's equations, you will realise where these right hand rules come from. One more thing: see edit.

Comment: *edit: while writing the answer, i forgot that an elecron is negative in charge and so the field will actually be in the opposite direction which the right hand rule gives.* I don't quite understand..a magnet is neutral but we can still use the rule on it...then why does the charge make a difference?

Comment: @MartianCactus It seems that you do not know the mathematical equations of Electrictity & Magnetism. I would recommend you to read [Feynman's lectures](http://feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/) to understand it. However I will still try to explain it in my answer.

Comment: can an atom have more than 1 unpaired electrons? If yes then what will happen if they don't share the same spin?

Comment: @MartianCactus Yes, an atom can have more than 1 unpaired electron (I am sure about this).  They will always have the same spin (I think. But you should confirm it on chemistry stackexchange).

Comment: thx for the edit!! But I still don't get how the magnetic field of a solenoid is defined..

Comment: For that I guess you should ask another question on this site . . . (otherwise this answer shall deviate too much from tge original topic)

Answer (score 1):

**First question**

Electrons have intrinsic angular momentum which does not arise from its motion in physical space (that is why it cannot be derived from Schrodinger's equation) and is called (fortunately or unfortunately) the **spin** angular momentum.
As this angular momentum has a direction, the isotropy of space is destroyed and now you can define an axis, or a direction.
With reference to the figure drawn in the video link, the spin angular momentum will be pointing vertically downwards, and the top of the electron simply means the tail of the spin angular momentum vector.
The magnetic moment of the electron is aligned antiparallel to the angular momentum, in this case the spin angular momentum.
Thus, the magnetic moment of the electron is pointing vertically upwards. There are no magnetic monopoles, but sometimes they are convenient to picture magnetic field lines. So in terms of magnetic monopoles, it is said that the North pole is above the electron. This simple means that, for given spin angular momentum, the magnetic dipole moment is vertically upwards.

**Second question**

Yes, higher-$Z$ atoms have paired electrons. They can have more than one paired electrons. They can have paired and unpaired electrons also. Kindly see some chemistry textbook how the electrons are filled in different orbitals. They give a simplified picture of the filling of energy levels and should be sufficient to address your concerns about the magnetic moment of an atom. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoNIQjW5Zxs) may help (honestly, I have not seen it though).

Comment: what happens if it has more than 1 unpaired electrons but the spin is in different directions? Which one will the atom have?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the electron doesn't spin on its axis. So, when he says spin, he's basically wrong. But about the pairing thing, it means two atoms share one electron each to remain stable.

Comment: Pairing, when talking abou magnetism, means that magnetic properties of an atom depend on the number of electrons...if all electrons are paired it means that all the states are filled, we have an even number of electrons. If you add one more electron now you have an odd number of them and that lonely guy on its own gives rise to a net magnetic moment of non-zero value.

Comment: Top or bottom of electron is decided dependin on its magnetic moment projection i guess, that part sound a bit clumsy.

Comment: +Žarko Tomičić can an atom have more than 1 unpaired electrons? If yes then what will happen if they don't share the same spin?